# There exists an element that comes after all others confusion

Tags: logic, quantifiers

*So I asked this question a month back but I realised something that was stated in the question stem and I am now confused:*

> Consider the predicate language with predicate symbol $<$, ***where $x<y$
> means that "$x$ is an object different from $y$ that comes before $y$"***,
> and $=$ is the usual equality symbol.
>
> Choose the first-order logic formulas that correctly translate the
> sentence:
>
> "There exists an element that comes after all others".
>
> A. $∃x∀y(y<x)$
>
> B. $∃x∀y(¬(y<x)→(y=x))$
>
> C. $∀x∃y(x<y)$
>
> D. $∃x∀y((y<x)∨(y=x))$

The correct options are B and D

I have two questions:

1. You see where I am confused is that people said that A and C are incorrect because A and C can mean the same object, however if you read the question stem it says in bold "where $x<y$ means that "$x$ is an object different from $y$ that comes before $y$" so surely the fact that they may point to the same object shouldn't be an issue because it clearly states that $x$ and $y$ are different objects
2. My second question is that don't you need to find just one element that comes after all others? So for A and C you just need to find a single element that comes after all others because of the $∃x$ and the $∃y$ part, so why is the issue that $x$ and $y$ may be the same object arising if you just need 1 element and there will always be an element greater than all others, say we consider the set of natural numbers for example

Comment: Surely you agree that $\forall x\forall y\,(x<y)$ is false if there are at least two elements, because one of the assignments made by $\forall x\forall y$ will be one where $y$ is an element that comes before $x$, thereby making $x<y$ false. Why is it then so difficult to envision that $x<y$ might be made false by one of the assignments made by $\forall x\forall y$ because that assignment assigned the same value to $x$ and to $y$?

Comment: The formulas are $ ∃x∀y(y<x)$ and $∀x∃y(x<y) $ not $  ∀x∀y(x<y)$ @DavidK

Comment: Yes, I see that, but you are saying that the formula $x<y$ has some kind of magic influence that forces the quantifiers prior to it to choose only distinct values. Does that influence extend to the $\forall x\forall y$ quantifiers or doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but this is different because thats how exists works, you just need to find one case (one element in this case) which is larger than all other elements and also the question stem says x and y are different objects @DavidK

Comment: Well, I'm here to tell you that the $\forall y$ doesn't care a rat's posterior about the fact that $\exists x$ may already have chosen the largest element or that the formula that comes after is $y<x.$ A universal quantifier is a universal quantifier and it ranges over **every** element, even the ones you wish it wouldn't, including the element that is the same as the one chosen by $\exists x$. Since $y<x$ is false for that value of $y,$ (because $y$ is not different from $x$), the entire predicate is false.

Comment: okay fair enough but then the question clearly states "where x<y means that "x is an object different from y that comes before y", so why are we worrying about if they could be the same object when the question says that x and y are different objects, if the question hasn't stated this then I would be like fair enough they can point to the same object which will then make the predicate false @DavidK

Comment: The definition says "$x$ is different from $y$" in the same way it says that "$x$ comes before $y$". It's just one of the conditions that you have to check when deciding whether $x<y$ is true or false. It is perfectly meaningful to write $2<2$, it's just false, just like $3<2$ is meaningful but false.

Comment: @DavidK - "A universal quantifier is a universal quantifier and it ranges over every element, even the ones you wish it wouldn't." That is possibly the best thing I've read on this site in all the years I've been on it. Take a (virtual) bow.

Comment: so if a universal quantifier ranges over all elements, including the element chosen by ∃x, then how could you ever have an element that comes over all others? because that element will be included in ∀y @DavidK

Comment: And that's exactly why A doesn't work. It is only true if there is an element $x$ such that $x<x.$ (C also doesn't work because it actually says there is no greatest element.) But B and D correctly handle the possibility that $y$ is the same as $x$.

Comment: You cannot have a greatest element x because you said any element you choose, will be included in the ∀y since u said it ranges over all elements, including the one chosen by ∃x, so if this is the case you cannot have an element greater than every element in y? So B and D can't be correct do you see what I'm saying @DavidK

Comment: unless you meant its not always the case that "A universal quantifier is a universal quantifier and it ranges over every element, even the ones you wish it wouldn't, including the element that is the same as the one chosen by ∃x.", but it can be the case @DavidK

Comment: Did you not notice the terms $y=x$ in B and D? That is what makes them different from A. The $\forall y$ ranges over all the elements, **including** the one chosen for $x$, and when $y$ is $x$ then $y=x$ is true and it makes the entire predicate true for that choice of $x$ and $y.$ Try it with a finite set (not the integers, they have no greatest element!). Set $x$ to the greatest element and cycle $y$ through all the elements including that one.

Comment: I don't think you're following what I am saying. You said the ∀y ranges over all elements, including the one chosen for x, so how can x possibly not be equal to y, it will always be the case that x=y (the largest element). For example if you have the set [1,2,3,4] the largest element here is 4 but 4 = 4, so all the elements come before 4 or is equal to 4, in a finite set how could you possible have an element greater than all the others (like for [1,2,3,4]) @DavidK

Comment: does this question assume a finite set or infinite set? does it change things? @DavidK

Comment: You didn't read my previous comment, did you? Maybe you need to seek out more local help (if you're in college there should be resources) rather than people on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to say or ask in part 2, but for part 1:  Yes, the *English* sentence says that you ste are looking for an element that is  greater than all *others* … but the *logical* sentences A and C do not specify that $x$ and $y$ are different …. which is exactly why they are wrong!

Comment: I don't understand, what makes this question different to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458805/is-option-d-correct-or-incorrect-for-this-formula-predicate-logic?noredirect=1#comment9340417_4458805, here option D is apparently correct but in this question C is wrong, they mean the same thing in different contexts

Comment: @computerscienceisapain For that other question: C is wrong, because it is saying that for every even number you can found some number smaller than it that is not even. And that is not true: $0$ is even but does not have a number smaller than it that is not even (at least not if the domain is understood to be the natural numbers ... if the domain was integers, then it would be a true statement.